# Is it possible to use NFCVASReaderSession to read Apple Wallet passes?

Tags: nfc, wallet, passkit, ios13, core-nfc

I am trying to use the new `NFCVASReaderSession` API on iOS 13 beta using an iPhone XR.

`NFCVASReaderSession.readingAvailable` is returning false, but when I call `session.begin()` it launches the scan UI.

A couple of questions:
Is there additional entitlements needed for this to work?? Or [should these work?](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_nfc_readersession_formats).

I have NFC enabled Apple Wallet VAS passes and have configured the `NFCVASReaderSession` to target the correct `passTypeIdentifier` but to no avail. Is this supposed to work with NFC enabled Apple Wallet passes or does anybody have any theories about what it is for?

```swift
let config = NFCVASCommandConfiguration(vasMode: .normal, passTypeIdentifier: passTypeIdentifier, url: nil)
session = NFCVASReaderSession(vasCommandConfigurations: [config], delegate: self, queue: nil)
session?.alertMessage = "Hold your iPhone near the VAS pass."
session?.begin()
```

Comment: I also get false for `readingAvailable` on an iPhone XS, but I haven't been able to get the scan UI to come up.

Comment: My current theory is it’s only for VAS enabled stickers for Apple Pay. Not sure it’s supposed to used with nfc enabled Apple wallet passes.

Comment: Any further thoughts or experience on this Scott, now that a year has passed?  Does your theory hold?  It would sure be nice to have a way to behave like a VAS terminal from an iOS app...

Comment: Hi @DelBrown, the last I remember I was able to read _encrypted_ VAS data using an iPhone with raw `iso7816` commands but I don't think I ever got it working with  NFCVASReaderSession to return `decrypted` payloads. Worth trying yourself because I was using an early beta of iOS 13 so it could have changed. You could use a service like PassNinja to decrypt it after reading if that fails. 
I left this project pretty half-baked because I moved onto other things :) Good luck

Comment: Thanks @ScottCondron.  I actually talked to someone later this morning who has built demos using this.  He says it is used for adding passes to the Apple Wallet, after the iPhone user scans a VAS enabled sticker/tag.  So your theory holds!

Comment: @ScottCondron were you able to get the NFCVASResponse back? I am seeing the scan UI as well, but I wasn't able to get the response when tapping the nfc pass.

Comment: Did you end up using NFCTagReaderSession or NFCVASReaderSession ?

Comment: NFCTagReaderSession using .iso7816 config and updating the info.plist with the correct AID from the tag. As I said, I would try again with NFCVasReaderSession too because I left the project early during ios 13 beta.

Comment: @ScottCondron got it, I tried with NFCVasReaderSession, but its not detecting it. How are you getting the correct AID?

Comment: Good question. It's the AID for wallet passes. IIRC it's also the same for Google Pay passes. 4F53452E5641532E3031 (OSE.VAS.01 ascii to hex)

Comment: @ScottCondron thank you! I can see it's picking up the tag now, but how do you see the encrypted payload? do you send apdu command?

Comment: sorry I don't have access to the work I did as I've moved on from Flomio & PassNinja, as far as I remember you need to send an APDU command but I _think_ the specific APDU is under NDA from Apple

Comment: got it. was it specific per application or the same for all?

Comment: I think it was specific to the identifier used to sign the pass but I don’t remember, sorry